# Angular Datatable export via ajax

Tags: angular

how can i populate the Datatable with the json data i got from backend? in console.log data appears correctly

i got the data but i cant send them in datatable i used many ways but all failed i instructions from http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way
were not very helpful

----------in html file-------

```
 <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover"><!--id="userTable"-->
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
        <th>Enabled</th>
        <th>isDoctor</th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th>DeleteAcc</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody *ngIf="patientUser?.length != 0">
    <tr *ngFor="let patient of patientUser">
        <td>{{patient.patientID}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.username}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.email}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{patient.enabled}}</td>
        <td [hidden]="patient.doctorIs"><a (click)="enableDoctor(patient.username)" style="cursor: pointer;">Enable</a></td>
        <td [hidden]="!patient.doctorIs"><a (click)="disableDoctor(patient.username)" style="cursor: pointer;">Disable</a></td>
        <td [hidden]="patient.enabled"><a (click)="enableUser(patient.username)" style="cursor: pointer;">Enable</a></td>
        <td [hidden]="!patient.enabled"><a (click)="disableUser(patient.username)" style="cursor: pointer;">Disable</a></td>
        <td ><a (click)="deleteUser(patient.patientID)" style="cursor: pointer;">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tbody *ngIf="patientUser?.length == 0">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3" class="no-data-available">No data!</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

-----in component file below------

```
    dtOptions: any = {};


    const that = this;
    let url = "http://localhost:8015/api/patient/all";
    this.dtOptions = {
        ajax: () => {
          that.http
            .get<UserAccountComponent>(
                url,
               {withCredentials: true}
            ).subscribe(resp => {
                this.test=JSON.stringify(resp);
              that.patientUser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(resp));
            });
        },
        // Declare the use of the extension in the dom parameter
        columns: [{
            title: 'ID',
            data: 'patientID'
          }, {
            title: 'First name',
            data: 'firstName'
          }, {
            title: 'Last name',
            data: 'lastName'
          }],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        // Configure the buttons
        buttons: [
          'columnsToggle',
          'colvis',
          'copy',
          'print',
          'excel'
        ]
      };
```

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: @Manit i actually do not get any errors the datatable is empty with the json sitting somewhere. It says ..loading... but the console debug nothins show for errors

Comment: Can you just keep the three properties i.e. ID, first name and last name in your template and then give this a try?

Comment: @Manit They do appear now you are correct! with this 3 properties its still says loading thought.... but when i press copy/csv/excel export nothing appears.

Comment: i think ajax call with data columns do not connect in someway, i think there is an error there

Comment: So, something is appearing that's a good news. What you should do is that remove the ajax part and hardcode the data for now in your component and in OnInit lifecycle do this: ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 3,
      processing: true,
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
        ]
    };
}

Comment: Just remove the ajax bit and see something work. Once you are through that we can look at the ajax specifically.

Comment: @Manit it works ! they to export now! without the ajax

Comment: great! so, is your ajax bit also working?

Comment: @Manit yeah it gets the json correctly and i can assign it to a class variable or any[]

Comment: try making an ajax call and assign to dtOptions and see if that works

Comment: @Manit I made a workaround by getting it from a observable seperate not in ajax call and it works correctly but i will give it a try because i want via ajax to succeed. Thank you i will try it and i will update my post for solution steps

Comment: cool! Shall I post the solution which I thought could have worked and upvote it if it helps?

Comment: Yeah totally i was actually seaching for any upvotes on comments but it does not have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that we tried all the things which are mentioned above in the comments (which was more like the way to debug). The final code in the component should be somewhat close to below one. Additionally someone can just make an ajax call and put it in a variable.

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
    patientUser: UserAccount[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        const that = this;

        this.dtOptions = {
            pagingType: 'full_numbers',
            pageLength: 2,
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
                that.http
                    .get<UserAccount>(
                        'http://localhost:8015/api/patient/all',
                        dataTablesParameters, {}
                    ).subscribe(resp => {
                        that.patientUser = resp.data; //would depend on resp object
                    });
            },
            columns: [{
                title: 'ID',
                data: 'patientID'
            }, {
                title: 'First name',
                data: 'firstName'
            }, {
                title: 'Last name',
                data: 'lastName'
            }],
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            // Configure the buttons
            buttons: [
                'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'print'
            ]
        };
    }
}
```